# Getting error trying to plot simple bar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

It looks a little weird because there is a blank space under `'product_id'`, but it is a dataframe.  I tested it with this method.

```
if isinstance(prod_names, pd.DataFrame):
    print('DF')
```

The DF comes from a count function.

```
prod_names = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('product_name')['product_id'].count().sort_values(ascending=False).head(20))
```

Now, I am trying to plot the results, like this.

```
pd.value_counts(prod_names['product_name']).plot.bar()
```

When I run that line of code, I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'product_name'
```

When I list the field names in the 'product_names' dataframe

```
list(prod_names)
```

I see only: `['product_id']`

For some reason, the `'product_name'` field is missing.  It may have something to do with the space under the `'product_id'`, but I'm not sure.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your product name here comes as an index. I don't see any other indexes here. And in this case you cannot access it through column name. You may or reset index(add new numerical column) via `prod_names.reset_index()` or alternatively just call `prod_names.index` to see product name info. In first case you can keep your function, in second you can modify it to smth like `pd.value_counts(prod_names.index).plot.bar()`